# Wireless dropping out periodically on laptop

Tags: wireless, internet

Recently a problem has started occurring on my laptop where the wireless connection is slow to connect and after about 30 seconds it disconnects. The Internet is also very slow when of works. It works fine on Windows and on my phone. Any help fixing this problem would be appreciated. (Or instructions on how to roll back a few days since this seems like a recent update has broken something)

Edit: never mind, it seems to have fixed itself. I guess it'll be a mystery that we'll never solve. Perhaps it was fixed by an update.

Edit2: I ran that script but it's being annoying and working at the moment. The output is here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10593061/ when it breaks again I'll post the script and we can compare. Thanks for your help.

Comment: To try to keep this short and quick, follow instructions from http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=370108 to run the wireless script and use paste.ubuntu.com to copy the wireless-info.txt file to and post the URL it gives

Comment: Please don't post information-free comments. This is a Q&A which is focused on working together on solutions. People will notice that you don't answer automatically.

Comment: This always happen or is usually after a resume from suspend? I'm asking because I had a bad experience with my wifi only after resume from suspend (then I had always to run a `sudo service restart network-manager`). It was so frustrating that I just added this command to run automatically at every resume.

Comment: @Rael always happening even after reboot.

Comment: @jeremy thanks. I'll post that when I get in from work.

Comment: any progress?  Or haven't you made it home?

Comment: @Jeremy31 yeah, I added an edit to the question but actually it has broken again so I'm just running that script as we speak (type)

Answer (score 0):

On what you posted, you only have two nearby access points broadcasting at higher signal strengths than yours!  Try changing channels, maybe the 2462 Frequency, with only weak signals present (at the time you ran the script).

Comment: And if that doesn't work, download the latest version of the driver from a mirror site from http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/amd64/bcmwl-kernel-source/download

Comment: Yeah, that didn't seem to work, I think it made it worse somehow. We'll try the driver tomorrow.